# Difference between "von... bis ..." , "von ... zu ..." ,''von ... bis zu ..."?

Tags: difference, preposition, conjunction

I'd like to ask  what is the difference between

> 1. von ... bis ...
> 2. von ... zu ...
> 3. von ... bis zu...,

and how should we use them?

e.g.:

"Vom Beginner zum Experten" oder "vom Beginner bis zum Experten"?

"vom Morgen bis zum Abend" oder "vom Morgen bis Abend"

"von Morgen**s** bis zu Abend**s**" oder "von Morgen**s** zu Abend**s**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are hardly any simple rules to follow, especially as semantics (the meaning and the broader context) play a crucial role.

The best thing you can do is get used to various correct (well-formed) expressions in their typical, appropriate context and use them.

Here are good (well-formed) sentences:

> Vom Anfänger [bis] zum Experten - alle waren zu dieser Konferenz eingeladen.

Both variations are possible. It is a question of taste which to choose.

> Vom Anfänger zum Experten ist es ein weiter Weg.

"Bis" could be used here, too, but it would sound a bit clumsy (my perception).

> Vom Morgen bis zum Abend haben wir Kühe gehütet.

That's for a concrete day; or at least the perspective the speaker takes is that of imagining a concrete day.

> Vom Morgen bis Abend haben wir Kühe gehütet.

Similar as the above, but a bit more casually expressed. You can speak so, but you should not write so.

> Von morgens bis abends haben wir Kühe gehütet.

That's for an unspecified quantity of days. It is a general description how at that time days were spent.

---

Note that some of your sample sentences are completely wrong (i.e. not well-formed):

- *von morgens bis zu abends [not existing form]
- *von morgens zu abends [not existing form]